# Nuxt Auth gives error after login complete via modal

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I am using nuxt-auth for my project in which I am using a modal for login purpose but after the login is done I get the following
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqxsS.png)

I tried looking into the error in depth and found that there is a `auth/auth.js` file in `.nuxt` in which there is a function which used the `this.ctx.route` var which does a `some()` on `this.ctx.route.matched` but there is no `.matched` in `this.ctx.route`

Any idea what might be the issue, login works perfectly but after that I get the error.

My main objective is that the user should not be redirected after login from modal.

Answer (score 0):

By default Nuxt Auth will redirect you to homepage. You can change this behaviour by changing redirect option in Nuxt Auth from nuxt.config.js file.
https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options